# SwiftUI - NavigationLink not working when clicked

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, macos-catalina

Currently using:

Xcode 11 Beta 5
Mac OSX Catalina Beta 5

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView : View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Product()) {
                Text("Click")
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation"))
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
#endif
```

And here is result:

[image]

When tapped or clicked on button, it should go to detail view, bit nothing is happening.

Notes:

- The Landmark example project by apple, is also not working when tapped on the landmarks on home screen.
- This website mentions that "Not sure if it is a bug or by design, in Beta 5 above code won't work"
  https://fuckingswiftui.com/#navigationlink

Answer (score 2):

It must be a bug. But as a workaround, when on the top view of a NavigationView, embed NavigationLink inside a VStack. The button will gain its proper style and "clickability".

```swift
struct SwiftUIView : View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
           VStack {
               NavigationLink(destination: Product()) {
                Text("Click")
               }
           }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Navigation"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works in Xcode(11.2)

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button("Press") {
                        self.selection = 1
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}
```