# SwiftUI - Navigation Link - doesn't work second time

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

In the following code, I've depicted the issue I'm facing.

- AddContentView - is having just a single label
- ContentView has a navigation link with a text and a navigation link.

The Navigation-link works fine for the first time but stops working afterwords.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AddContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                NavigationLink(destination: AddContentView()) {
                    Text("Navigate")
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("First")
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to the demo attached here.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483962/swiftui-unable-to-navigate-back-and-forth-with-navigationlink/59484980#59484980

Comment: Okay but can't delete the question now - You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Comment: I didn't mean to tell you for delete question. I just want to tell you you can use that solution until we get any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simulator bug only, if you have a device to test on the `NavigationLink` works correctly multiple times. Hopefully Apple will fix this soon.

Comment: Workaround: for me it works again if you present sheet from the same view and come back